# Sort list from a specific index value in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing, sublist

I want to sort a python list from a specific index. Here is what I want to achieve.
Consider a list `al = [1,2,4,3]`
Now what I want to do is, start from the last index, go back and swap the number which is smaller than the last index, i.e 2 which is at index 1.
now my list is `[1,3,4,2]`

But, after swapping I want to sort the sub-list after the swapped index.
instead of `[1,3,4,2]`
I want to get to `[1,3,2,4]`
Is there any way in python to only sort the sub-list?
Right now if I use the sort method for a particular index for example:
`al[2:].sort()` It creates a new list instead of changing the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `sorted()` on a slice and then assign the result back to the slice:

```
al[2:] = sorted(al[2:])
```

Comment: Alright, so there is no other function like list.sort() to sort the list without assignment?

Comment: @EkwinderSaini: Not with a general list. But if the data you're working on can fit in bytes (i.e., 0-255) you could use a  [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) on a  bytearray. But there's probably not much point unless your collection is huge - the list slice argument to `sorted()` created by NPE's code is only temporary & will be quickly garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it inplace and depending on what you have in your lists, you could use numpy where [basic indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) using  always returns a [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) of the original array:

```
import numpy as np

al = np.array([1, 2, 4, 3])

n = np.where(al < al[-1])[0][-1]
al[n], al[-1] = al[-1], al[n]
al[n+1:].sort()

print(al)
[1 3 2 4]
```